# Increment the value of a column initiated with null in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need help please to increment automatically value of a column initiated with null value like this:

[image]

the problem is when I want to increment it like this :

```
UPDATE `mape` SET id_subjekta = IFNULL(id_subjekta, 0) + 1;
```

I get this error :

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UNIQ_B3FABDF46545572'
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using MariaDB

Comment: Please add a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zPM4LGDi).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you may be adding more data to this table in the future, you may just want to generate this sequence at the time you query.  Assuming the `id` column provide the order, you could try:

```sql
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS id_subjekta_2
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY 2;
```

Comment: I get : 3 errors were found during analysis.

An alias was previously found. (near "id_subjekta" at position 45)
An alias was expected. (near " " at position 44)
Unexpected token. (near "id_subjekta" at position 45)

Comment: I get the same error?

Comment: No, you should not be getting any errors now.

Comment: An alias was previously found. (near "id_subjekta_2" at position 45)
An alias was expected. (near " " at position 44)
Unexpected token. (near "id_subjekta_2" at position 45)

Comment: I use MariaDB that why I got errors